# Wiring the Mean Well RT 125D

Tags: power-supply, connector, wiring

For some projects with the Raspberry PI 2, for which I require 5V+12+24V, I baught the [Mean Well RT-125D](http://www.distrelec.ch/Web/Downloads/sp/ec/tmRT-125-spec.pdf?mime=application%2Fpdf)

I put the switch in order to have "230V" displayed, as in my Country, the voltage is 230V.

I put the brown wire on the "L", the blue on the N and the green-yellow to the ground:
[image: Wiring].

I put the plug, and I checked with the multimeter, I have 230V. I checked the voltage between the Pole "+5V" and the pole "COM". But it varies(seems to go from 0V to 5V each second). Additionally the green led on the right of the pole is blinking(at the same frequency than the 0 to 5V). I hear also a small noise, at the same frequency also.

Is there something that I'm missing? Or is this power supply defect?

Comment: You noticed that each channel has a current *range*, not just a current *limit*, right?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, but in my case I'm checking the voltage, not the current

Answer (score 3):

You have no load connected, and the data sheet you cited shows minimum loads for each rail (2A for 5V, 0.4A for +24V, 0.1A for 12V).

Not all power supplies can operate at zero load. Operating the power supply outside of specification (i.e. less than the specified current range) isn't guaranteed by the datasheet. Most likely it's losing regulation and shutting down to protect itself.

Try connecting some load and try again. If you have the minimum load on all 3 outputs and the unit still hiccups on and off, it may be defective.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, I wasn't aware of that. Since I've the D version, it would mean that I have to have at least 0.4A for the 24V(which I'm using), right? Because I just tried to put a fan, which according to his specs, should use 24V and 710mA, so it should work, no? Because after doing that, I just have my fan which seems to start and stop, what can I do? The fan is this one: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/120/6200N-276038.pdf More precisely, the 6224N

Comment: I fixed my answer with the correct current specs for the D-model. You may have to experiment with loading any / all of the outputs.

Comment: thank you for your help, it makes a very long time I've made electronic. Just to be sure, if I put an adequate resistance on each, it should work right? This would mean: R of 2.5Ohm max on 5V, 60Ohm max on 24V and 120Ohm max on 12V? But this makes very very small values, I feel I didn't understood something(and I don't have such small resistor)

Comment: Is this the right law to use?

Comment: Yes, simple R = V / I applies to this. Make sure your loads are rated for the power you intend to draw.

Comment: Ok, but I've really no idea where to found a 2.5 Ohm resistance :/. The lowest I can find is 10 Ohm

Comment: Put 4 in parallel.

Comment: Oh! I had forgot this 1/RTot = 1/R1 + 1/R2 +... I test this tomorrow, the lowest resistance I have right now is a 220Ohm, which, if I computed correclty, would require 88 of them to have 2.5 Ohm at the end :)

Comment: I have a same model of power supply. But I have follow your discussion and put the load accordingly at all output, but still failed to make the power supply working well, how about you?