# Meanwell RT125D supply behaviour

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, current-limiting

I am using a [meanwell RT125D](http://www.meanwell.com/productPdf.aspx?i=491) power supply which has

```
230 V AC input and 3 O/P i.e. 5V, 12V and 24V.
```

While I used the supply, without any load, the behaviour of supply was not as I expected. The   LED in the supply was blinking at a interval of 1 second ([as show in this representative video](https://youtu.be/Ye8CmR6L8uI))and no where in the datasheet  can I find out the reason for such behaviour. In the video itself people have suggested to load both 5V and 12V. I tried that also, but the same behaviour continued.

Further, I found out some one has asked the [similar question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179273/wiring-the-mean-well-rt-125d). Although I have not tried adding resistance but that don't seems to be a proper way. Also I would like to as if I had missed any thing in datasheet (i.e. in the other electrical exchange, I found out that minimum current for RT125D for each of supply is 2 Amp, .4Amp and .1 Amp for 5, 12 and 24V).

Need help to resolve this.

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: Meanwell do not always mean well.

Comment: I have dropped them a mail. And waiting for their reply.

Comment: Recently got a email from Meanwell saying that by Range 2.0 to 15V , they means 2Amp is the minimum current requirement. I don't know if 2 Amp is minimum current requirement for the 5V or for whole of the supply and when i put a RPI (5V and 1 amp) and our sound senor(12 V , .25 Amp), supply get stabilise.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it was the over voltage protection on the 5Volt output that caused your problems.

Unloaded, the 5V line went over 5.75 Volts, causing the power supply to go into "hiccup" mode where it shuts off the output, waits a while, then tries it again, over and over until the over voltage condition goes away.

The datasheet doesn't have an explicit entry for the minimum load for 5V, but it is rated for 2A to 15A (maximum), nominal 8A.  So, it probaly needs a relatively large minimum load to behave correctly.

2A at 5V is a resistance of 2.5Ohms, so pick something that needs a lot of power.
If you try with a resistor, it would need to be rated for 10Watts.

Comment: Hi - Agreed with this hypothesis of the behaviour (+1). You said "The datasheet doesn't mention a minimum load for 5V" - However the PSU spec showing the 5V output (for example) is rated for 2A to 15A, and not 0A to 15A, *is* showing a minimum load requirement of 2A, isn't it? (Similar, but lower currents, for the other two rails.)

Comment: @SamGibson:  Mmm.  Yeah.  I'll change that.

Comment: @JRE - Problem with adding a resistor to the o/p supply will be wastage of lot of power , around 25 watt. Probably i did a mistake by selecting this supply. There is another power supply from them RT50D with 51Watt power. In that minimum current for 5V is .6 Amp. Probably i will use that.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else comes across this, check https://www.meanwell.com/newsInfo.aspx?c=2&i=758

Mean-well changed the design in a number of their multi voltage power supplies, so that the minimum load is not required anymore. Instead of using new type numbers for their supplies, they sell them under the new name. Even though they have the same name as older versions of the same power supply, they have different characteristics.

The datasheets of these units have been updated, but do not mention the required minimum load of the older versions anymore. I would think they would at least put in a notification, but that is not the case.
So the datasheet for the RT-125D (which I have) shows no minimum load for this model, but mine was made with the older design, so it needs the minimum load. Took me a while to find out that the datasheet was not 100% relevant...